# What is the overhead of an "synchronized" async method?

Tags: c#, async-await

Here is a benchmark for methods return task, but run synchronizely under the hood.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static async Task<int> UsingAsyncModifier()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public static Task<int> UsingTaskCompletionSource()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        tcs.SetResult(10);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public static Task<int> UsingTaskFromResult()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(10);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
        const int repeat = 10000; // Results volatile while repeat grows.
        Console.WriteLine("Repeat {0} times.", repeat);

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
        {
            j += UsingAsyncModifier().Result;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("UsingAsyncModifier: {0}", DateTime.Now - t);
        t = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
        {
            j += UsingTaskCompletionSource().Result;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("UsingTaskCompletionSource: {0}", DateTime.Now - t);
        t = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
        {
            j += UsingTaskFromResult().Result;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("UsingTaskFromResult: {0}", DateTime.Now - t);
    }
}
```

**Output** (repeat 10,000/100,000/1000,000 times):

```
Repeat 10000 times.
UsingAsyncModifier: 00:00:00.1043980
UsingTaskCompletionSource: 00:00:00.0095270
UsingTaskFromResult: 00:00:00.0089460
```

Repeat 10,000 times, UsingTaskFromResult 10x faster than *UsingAsyncModifier*.

```
Repeat 100000 times.
UsingAsyncModifier: 00:00:00.1676000
UsingTaskCompletionSource: 00:00:00.0872020
UsingTaskFromResult: 00:00:00.0870180
```

Repeat 100,000 times, UsingTaskFromResult 2x faster than *UsingAsyncModifier*.

```
Repeat 1000000 times.
UsingAsyncModifier: 00:00:00.8458490
UsingTaskCompletionSource: 00:00:00.8870980
UsingTaskFromResult: 00:00:00.9027320
```

Repeat 1,000,000 times, *UsingAsyncModifier* slightly faster than UsingTaskFromResult.

What I think was, the `async` modifier just created an completed Task, something like `Task.FromResult()` does. But the benchmark does not prove my idea.
Why?

Comment: The fact that at very high iterations the times were virtually identical likely means that the differences in the lower iterations were based on noise, GC collections, context switches, and other errors with the benchmarking framework.  Also note `DateTime.Now` doesn't really have good enough precision to measure times that short.  Benchmarking code snippets that execute *that* fast is *really* hard.  In essense, your tests are not actually saying anything meaningful at all; the margin of error is so high as to render the results effectively meaningless.

Comment: It's also worth noting that your first method is so simple that it might just be optimised away by the compiler.  It's even possible that it might run synchronously (I know with the WPF `Dispatcher` classes it's possible for a background job to run so fast that it appears to the caller as a completed before the async request has returned).  As @Servy suggests, your tests aren't really going to be meaningful under these conditions.

Comment: @DanPuzey, the `async`-ed method without (or until) `await` runs synchronously. Though, it cannot be run without returning  a task for wrapping the returned result. I believethe ppl using `async` understood correctly what I've wrote without breaking my head how to write it less ambiguously in more length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I see the similar results using `DateTime`, the use of `Stopwatch` for time measuring  shows that iterations using  `UsingAsyncModifier()` take 2 times more time duration (than using `UsingTaskCompletionSource()` or `UsingTaskFromResult()`, both showing equal appr. duration) even with  1 000 000  iterations

Here is output:

```
Repeat 1000000 times.
UsingAsyncModifier: 5458
UsingTaskCompletionSource: 2838
UsingTaskFromResult: 2556
```

with your code using `Stopwatch`

```
class Program
{
     public static async Task<int> UsingAsyncModifier()
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public static Task<int> UsingTaskCompletionSource()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        tcs.SetResult(10);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
    public static Task<int> UsingTaskFromResult()
    {
        return TaskEx.FromResult(10);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
      Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
      const int repeat = 1000*1000; // Results volatile while repeat grows.
      Console.WriteLine("Repeat {0} times.", repeat);

        int j = 0;
        //DateTime t = DateTime.Now;
        timer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
        {
            j += UsingAsyncModifier().Result;
        }
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("UsingAsyncModifier: {0}"
                          , timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        //t = DateTime.Now;
        timer.Reset();

        j = 0;

        timer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
        {
            j += UsingTaskCompletionSource().Result;
        }
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("UsingTaskCompletionSource: {0}"
                           , timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        //t = DateTime.Now;
        timer.Reset();
        j = 0;
        timer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
        {
          j += UsingTaskFromResult().Result;
        }
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("UsingTaskFromResult: {0}"
                          , timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Stephen Toub in his "[Async Performance: Understanding the Costs of Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)" explains:

> When working with synchronous code, methods with empty bodies are
>   practically free. This is not the case for asynchronous methods

Read it for much more details